# How to design XPages JS functions for use in library?

Tags: xpages

Creating XPages application that replaces users filling out a simple Excel and mailing it to users.

So to start with I have two Edit Boxes on the form, Hours10 and Hours20.

Want the value input into Hours20 to also go to Hours10.

When I have this code in the onChange event of the Hours20 edit box

```
var hours20 = XSP.getElementById("#{id:Hours20}").value; 
XSP.getElementById("#{id:Hours10}").value = hours20;
```

It works and the Hours10 edit box is updated with value from Hours20.

When I move the code into a function that is saved in a client side javascript library:

```
function updateHours() {
  var hours20 = XSP.getElementById("#{id:Hours20}").value; 
  XSP.getElementById("#{id:Hours10}").value = hours20; 
}
```

and call it from the onChange event of the Hours20 edit box: updateHours();

It does not work.  Gives me an object not found error on the XSP object.

Not sure why it is giving error - my guess is that XSP is no longer in Scope?

Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expression Language (e.g. `#{id:Hours20}`) can only be interpreted within the context of a component attribute, such as the `onChange` event code for a field. Once you move the code into a separate library, the code is no longer an attribute of a component, it's code that can be *referenced* in component attributes.

As with any other good function, design all client-side JavaScript functions to accept anything that might be context-sensitive as a parameter. For example:

```
function updateHours(inputId, outputId) {
  var hours20 = XSP.getElementById(inputId).value; 
  XSP.getElementById(outputId).value = hours20; 
}
```

Then your `onChange` event can reference this function, but pass in only the context-sensitive information:

```
updateHours("#{id:Hours20}", "#{id:Hours10}");
```

This way you're keeping reusable business logic in script libraries, which is always a good thing, but nothing in those libraries is assuming anything about page structure or server-side variables.

Comment: Hmm... I thought that EL is not parsed in JavaScript libraries, only when added directly to a XPage (f.e. in a scriptblock) It does not depend on the context of a component/event. Or have I missed something?

Comment: This is indeed an interesting topic: f.e. I often have wondered why it is possible to use "getComponent" in a *ssjs*-library (I personally avoid that, but I've seen working implementations)

Comment: @LotharMueller: Why should it not possible to use *getComponent* in a SSJS lib?

Comment: Sven, you're half right: EL is only parsed when added to an XPage, *because* it is dependent upon component context, particularly SSJS, which needs to know what `this` refers to. That's why both `ValueBindingEx` and `MethodBindingEx` have a `setComponent` method: it establishes that context. SSJS in a library has no context; code on an XPage that calls library functions *does* have context and can pass that in. CSJS libraries are sent directly to the browser with no EL interpretation performed; a `scriptBlock` is a component, so its renderer evaluates any value bindings when sending the tag.

Comment: Lothar, because library code that includes `getComponent` can only be triggered by a `MethodBindingEx` with component context, the Java underpinnings of that function know "where" it was called from, and can use that context to attempt to find the closest component with a matching ID. But you're wise to avoid calling this function, as there is nearly always a better approach. The two valid cases for `getComponent` are custom validators where one value's validity is dependent upon the submitted value of another component, and triggering component events (i.e. `getComponent('dialog').show();`).

Comment: @Sven: can't really tell, I just find it odd that it should be allowed in the first place. But this is not the place to go into detail, I'm afraid ;)

Comment: @Tim: many thanks for your comprehensive answers; helpful as always!

Comment: @TimTripcony: In SSJS, EL Expressions are not parsed. That's all about it. you cannot use EL Expressions directly in SSJS, it does not matter if it is in a libarary or directly on the XPage.